# Frequency count of char in array python

Tags: python

I have an array of cathegory characters

```
x = ['ca','bd','lo',...]
```

And I'd like to find the frequency of each of these cathegories.

Basically a list like this

```
y = [[2,'ca'],[0,'bd'],[10,'lo'],...]
```

Is there an easy way in python?

Thanks!

Comment: `collections.Counter` will do this.

Comment: But this function requieres that I know the different cathegories, right?

Comment: how will collections.Counter count zero items like `[0,'bd']`?

Comment: are there always going to be two characters in the categories array? I ask because there needs to be some way to create character combinations to check for which are not in the list. zero frequency items like `[0,'bd']` could be checked for from a list created by using something like `collections.combinations()`, that can check for categories without first knowing the categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a `list` of `lists` you can use `list-comprehesion` as the following:

```
x = ['ca','bd','lo']
y = [[x.count(z), z] for z in set(x)]
```

This will output:

```
[[1, 'bd'], [1, 'lo'], [1, 'ca']]
```

Comment: Thank you, this was excactly what i was looking for

Comment: Note that this isn't efficient at all compared to `Counter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
x = ['ca','bd','lo']
Counter(x)
# Counter({'bd': 1, 'lo': 1, 'ca': 1})
Counter(x).items()
# [('bd', 1), ('lo', 1), ('ca', 1)]
```

No need to pre-define any category. If you try to fetch a category which isn't present in the original list, `counter` simply returns 0:

```
count = Counter(x)
count['not_here']
# 0
```